# How to Insert binary data with in insert query into Postgresql using jdbc

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have table structure like below

```sql
CREATE  TABLE PUBLIC.STAFF(
    STAFF_ID INT NOT NULL,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    ADDRESS_ID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    PICTURE BYTEA,
    EMAIL VARCHAR(50),
    STORE_ID INT NOT NULL,
    ACTIVE BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    USERNAME VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    PASSWORD VARCHAR(40),
    LAST_UPDATE TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

and I have couple of  insert queries in script file or stored in arraylist like

```sql
INSERT INTO STAFF(STAFF_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, ADDRESS_ID, PICTURE, EMAIL, STORE_ID, ACTIVE, USERNAME, PASSWORD, LAST_UPDATE)
VALUES (
    1,
    'Mike',
    'Hillyer',
    3,
    X'89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d4948445200000079000000750802000000e55ad965000000097048597300000ec300000ec301c76fa8640000200049444154789c4cbb7794246779ffbbf78f7b7ebe466177677772ce3d9d667aa67ba62776ce39545557ce3974ee9eb049ab95563922104142580830d10203061bb049064cb031d916c160100284505aedee4cdd3f16b8b7ce73de53f5d61f75cee7bcf53ccff7fb561dbb7ce9ad972fbdf5aecb6fbd74e7a3b75f7ef4ce7bde72e9ae375fbaffcd676ebff7e29d658c864812c0e90acec0040d123aad8a284f950906205810672b140d900226b218c713028f0a5c8',
    'Mike.Hillyer@sakilastaff.com',
    1,
    TRUE,
    'Mike',
    '8cb2237d0679ca88db6464eac60da96345513964',
    TIMESTAMP '2006-02-15 04:57:16.0'
);
```

When I am trying to insert the data into postgres using JDBC program I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "picture" is of type bytea but expression is of type bit
LINE 2: (1, 'Mike', 'Hillyer', 3, X'89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d49484452..                                 
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "picture" is of type bytea but expression is of type bit
```

How to solve this issue using `Java`?

Comment: Have you thought on using a `blob` instead of a `bytea`? BTW, what's the type of your Java attribute `picture`?

Comment: Try `'\X89504e47.....'` instead of `X'89504e47....'`.

Comment: You should be using a `PreparedStatement` in the first place. Then you can use `setBytes()`, without the need to escape the binary data.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when accessing form java it is recommended to use prepared statement. An example can be found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/jdbc-binary-data.html).

But sometimes you need to do it in SQL. In this case should use slightly different notation. Just use \x at the beginning of a string like follows (no need for any special prefixes, but note that x is lowercase):

```
'\x89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d4948445200000079000000750802000000e55ad965000000097048597300000ec300000ec301c76fa8640000200049444154789c4cbb7794246779ffbbf78f7b7ebe466177677772ce3d9d667aa67ba62776ce39545557ce3974ee9eb049ab95563922104142580830d10203061bb049064cb031d916c160100284505aedee4cdd3f16b8b7ce73de53f5d61f75cee7bcf53ccff7fb561dbb7ce9ad972fbdf5aecb6fbd74e7a3b75f7ef4ce7bde72e9ae375fbaffcd676ebff7e29d658c864812c0e90acec0040d123aad8a284f950906205810672b140d900226b218c713028f0a5c8'
```

Note that older versions of PostgreSQL only supported Escape Format which uses octal form to encode arbitrary bytes, not hex. Also note that Escape Format needs ::bytea ending.

Details can be found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-binary.html) (substitute version in the url to whichever you are using).

P.S. Obviously way too late for the original question, but this is where an online search lands. So, documenting it here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
E'\\x89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d4948445200000079000000750802000000e55ad965000000097048597300000ec300000ec301c76fa8640000200049444154789c4cbb7794246779ffbbf78f7b7ebe466177677772ce3d9d667aa67ba62776ce39545557ce3974ee9eb049ab95563922104142580830d10203061bb049064cb031d916c160100284505aedee4cdd3f16b8b7ce73de53f5d61f75cee7bcf53ccff7fb561dbb7ce9ad972fbdf5aecb6fbd74e7a3b75f7ef4ce7bde72e9ae375fbaffcd676ebff7e29d658c864812c0e90acec0040d123aad8a284f950906205810672b140d900226b218c713028f0a5c8'
```

Comment: This is working!